# Total Wages By Year/Quarter based on highest sequence number per each quarter and each year

Tags: sql-server

consider a table

```
employee id    report_year  report_quarter  sequencenumber quarter1_wage quarter2_wage 
101                2015       1              1              1000           0
101                2015       1              2              2000           0
102                2016       2              1              3000           0
102                2016       2              2               0            4000
```

The Result of the query must be

```
      Total wages

         6000
```

As in 2015 Employee id 101 with Highest sequence number 2 has 2000 comes under quarter1 as report _quarter is indicating it is 1 need to add take this value and add to the

2016 Employee id 102 with highest sequence number 2 has 4000(quarter2_wage) 
as report _quarter is indicating it is 2

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why you want to sum this way, but ignoring that you are going to be aggregating across quarters and thus the name "Total Wages" is mis-leading, here is how you accomplish that.

```
--Assign a row number per employee based off the sequence number.
--This will assign 1 to the highest sequence number for each employee
with cte as(
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [employee id] order by sequencenumber desc) as rn
        from yourTable)


--Sum and add the two quarters for all employees where the row number = 1
--Which is the highest sequence
select
    sum(quarter1_wage) + sum(quarter2_wage) as TotalWages
from cte
    where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
WITH cte0 AS(
SELECT 101 AS employeeid,2015 AS report_year,1 AS report_quarter,1 AS sequencenumber,1000 AS quarter1_wage,0 AS quarter2_wage union all
SELECT 101              ,2015               ,1                  ,2                  ,2000                 ,0                  union all
SELECT 102              ,2016               ,2                  ,1                  ,3000                 ,0                  union all
SELECT 102              ,2016               ,2                  ,2                  ,0                    ,4000        
),
cte1 as(
SELECT employeeid,report_year,report_quarter,MAX(sequencenumber) AS maxseqnum
FROM cte0
GROUP BY employeeid,report_year,report_quarter)
SELECT SUM(quarter1_wage+quarter2_wage) AS [Total wages]
FROM cte0 c0
    INNER JOIN cte1 c1
        ON c0.report_year = c1.report_year AND c0.report_quarter = c1.report_quarter AND c0.employeeid = c1.employeeid AND c0.sequencenumber = c1.maxseqnum
```